# Is there a last_insert_id method for Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

After an insert, I need to know the ID from the row, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Dataset#insert documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#M000402), the return value for `insert()` is usually the primary key of the inserted row, but it depends which adapter you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with SQL-Server and a uniqueidentifier, but without success. The uniqueidentifier is not returned.

Extract from my Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
     [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
     [Data] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ID]
```

When I insert with Sequel:

```
DB[:MyTable].insert( :Data => 'data' )
```

the dataset is added with a uniqueidentifier, but the return code if Dataset#insert is `nil`.

With

```
DB[:MyTable].insert(:ID => Sequel.function(:newid),  :Data => 'data' )
```

you get the same result.

I tried

```
key = Sequel.function(:ID)
DB[:MyTable].insert(:ID => key,  :Data => 'data' )
```

but 'key' is only the function call, not the value. With `Sequel.function(:ID).f` you get an *"Invalid column name ID'."*-error

But if you use a Model, the you get the uniqueidentifier:

```
class MyTable < Sequel::Model(:MyTable); end 
entry = MyTable.create(:Data => 'data')
$uniqueidentifier = entry[:ID]
```